# How many ways are there to select a three digit number $\underline{A}\ \underline{B}\ \underline{C}$ so that $A \neq B$, $B \leq C$, and $A < C$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to select a three digit number $\underline{A}\ \underline{B}\ \underline{C}$ so that $A \neq B$, $B \leq C$, and $A < C$?

---

I found the answer as $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{9} (k^2-k)=240$ by evaluating some big summations. I was wondering if anyone had a solution that doesn't require evaluating big sums?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: Since you say "number," I take it that the first digit can't be zero ?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure $A\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the three digits are distinct and non-zero, then there are two ways to arrange any selection of three digits from $\{1,\cdots, 9\}$.  Thus this gives us $2\times \binom 93=168$ cases.

If $B=0$, there are $\binom 92=36$ choices.

If $B=C>0$ there are $\binom 92=36$ choices.

And we are done, with $168+36+36=240$ cases.

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking for a solution like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let us split this into two cases: $A<B$ and $B<A$.

To count the number of solutions with $A<B$ we have $0<A<B\leq C\leq 9$, so we instead pick $A-1, B-A-1, C-B$, and we note that those are all non-negative integers, and if we include $9-C$ (which is also a non-negative integer) those satisfy:
$$
(A-1)+(B-A-1)+(C-B)+(9-C)=7
$$
In fact, *any* solution to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=7$ in the non-negative integers corresponds to exactly one choice of $A,B,C$ with $0<A<B\leq C\leq 9$, so we want the number of solution in the non-negative integers to the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=7
$$
The ["Stars and Bars" method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) (Wikipedia link, see Theorem two) tells us that there are $\binom{7+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{10}{3}=120$ solutions to the above equation in the non-negative integers.

To count the number of solutions with $B<A$ we have $0\leq B < A < C\leq 9$, so we instead pick $B, A-B-1, C-A-1$, and similarly to before we get
$$
B+(A-B-1)+(C-A-1)+(9-C)=7
$$
We get the same equation, and we again want the number of solutions in the non-negative integers, which is again $120$.

So in total we get $240$ solutions.

Comment: very nice $+1$ , B.T.W you can facilitate your work using the idea of bijection.. Assume that if $0<A<B \leq C \leq 9$ , then $0<A<B <C' <11$.Now just select $3$ numbers form the set of $\{1,2,..,10\}$ by $C(10,3)=120$.This is also valid for $0<B<A \leq C \leq 9$. So , $2 \times 120 =240$

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want to find how many choices of $A,B,C\in\{0,1,2,3,\dots, 9\}$ such that $A\ne B$, $B\leq C$ and $A<C$.

First, $C$ can not be $0$, otherwise we would not be able to choose $A<C$.
Let us then choose $C\in\{1,2,3,\dots, 9\}$. There are $9$ ways of choosing $C$.
We then have $(C+1)-1=C$ ways of choosing $A<C$. Finally, there are $C-1$ ways of choosing $B\ne A$ such that $B\leq C$. As a result, there are :
$$\sum_{C=1}^{9}C\cdot (C-1) =240$$
ways of choosing $A,B,C$.

Comment: Yes, this is the method I used. I was wondering if there is a method without the sum.

Comment: I will think about it, but I don't think so.